# Font does not load (or render) from css file

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to us a custom font in my html-file. I have uploaded the font files to github and hosted a css file on github. I checked several times that the links work and that the font-files contain actual fonts. My problem is that the text in the HTML document is displayed in the standard font and not in the 'kievit' font. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Thank you!

The CSS code in kievit.css is:

```css
@font-face {
                      font-family: 'kievit';
                      src: local('kievit'),url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/../Kievit-Medium.woff) format('woff');
                     src: local('kievit'), url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/../Kievit-Medium.eot);
        }
     @font-face {
                              font-family: 'kievit';
                              font-style: italic;
                              font-weight: bold;
                              src: local('kievit'), url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/../Kievit-BoldItalic.woff) format('woff');
                             src: local('kievit'), url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/../Kievit-BoldItalic.eot);
                }
```

```html
 


        <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://rawgit.com/../kievit.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
        <span style="font-family: 'kievit', sans-serif; font-size: 36px;"> Making the Web Beautiful</span>
        <br> <br>
        <span style="font-family: 'arial'; font-size: 36px;"> Making the Web Beautiful</span>
    </html>
```

Edit: I changed the font-style to font-family as suggested, but it still does not work. I the first line is still rendered in arial instead of my custom font.

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-family: 'kievit'` rather than `font-style`

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely a mistake, but it still does not work. It still does not load the font.

Comment: I just did (again). The file are definitely hosted under this URL.

Comment: I also tried to copy the css code into the head of the html document and it did not work. Is there any way to test directly whether the font is loaded? The URL definitely works (Firefox promts me to download the file when when I use the URL). I am sorry to ask so basic questions.

Comment: Check this link . Hope it helps you  http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather place a comment, however I don't have enough reputation to do so. At first sight your code looks ok, but there could be some other errors behind the screens (blocking network requests, wrong mime-type passing) So it would be easier to debug if you could provide us with a live example.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. I can't share this particular font, but I will try to set up a life example tomorrow.